# UI Button добавление событий через скрипт

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем добрый день! Создаю игру на Unity, в ней есть окно с номерами уровней. Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку определённого уровня открывается не выбранный уровень, а уровень с последним значением итерируемой переменной i. Заранее спасибо

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class LevelButtonController : MonoBehaviour
{
private int _levelToLoad;
public int _LevelToLoad
{
    get
    {
        return _levelToLoad;
    }

    set
    {
        _levelToLoad = value < 1 ? 1 : value;
    }
}

void Start()
{
    _LevelToLoad = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("NextLevel");

    for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Button>().interactable = i < _levelToLoad ? true : false;
        transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { PrintButtonNumber(i); });
        transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Button>().onClick.Invoke();
    }


    //PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();
}

void PrintButtonNumber(int i)
{
    Debug.Log(i);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты передаешь **i** как параметр, а в конце итерации и на момент нажатия на кнопку она равна  **transform.childCount**

Решить можно через локальный параметр

```
     for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
     {
        ...
        int p = i;
        transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Button>()
        .onClick.AddListener(()=> { PrintButtonNumber(p); });
         ...
     }
```

> The following rules apply to variable scope in lambda expressions:
>
> A variable that is captured will not be garbage-collected until the
> delegate that references it becomes eligible for garbage collection.

[отсюда](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20lambda%20declaration%20operator,block%20on%20the%20other%20side.&text=When%20you%20use%20method%2Dbased%20syntax%20to%20call%20the%20Enumerable.)

Это значит что делегат будет ссылаться на **i**, а она будет существовать, пока существует делегат. Так как это ссылка, то любые изменения **i** до вызова делегата повлияют на его результат.

В то время как **int p** создается заново каждую итерацию и не может быть изменен.

И еще одно **onClick** устарел:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.Button-onClick.html

Comment: Спасибо, помогло